# How the lightning arrestor works in an aircraft?

Tags: charge, lightning

The doubt may look silly. I referred the article about this in http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-happens-when-lightni/

It says that the current will exit through some extremity like tail. But as per my understanding there will be charge stored on the exterior of the plane. Wouldn't this be causing some issues because then it will be like a charged sphere moving through the charged clouds with opposite polarity. I would like get an explanation regarding how the lightning currents  are handled in planes, missiles etc.

Comment: Lightning protection for equipment in aircraft is a *huge* topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[What are these things hanging off the trailing edge of the wing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/what-are-these-things-hanging-off-the-trailing-edge-of-the-wing?noredirect=1&lq=1)" in Aviation.SE.

Static charges are drained by adding sharp-pointed "wicks" to the trailing edges of the body. The sharp points concentrate the electric field, facilitating the creation of corona discharge.